# SSO SharePoint 2013 for 2 domains

Tags: c#, sharepoint, asp.net-membership, single-sign-on, sharepoint-2013

Hi We are building apps with sharepoint 2013. Currently we have them setup as two web applications with two separate domain names -

- Wep App 1 - www.webapp1.com
- Web App 2 - www.webapp2.com

We also have ASP.net membership role provider database which we use for authentication.
right now we want to implement Single Sign On for both the Web App. If i Authenticate with one web app and i try to navigate to the other web app i should not be asked to re-authenticate again.

---

How can i achieve this. i cannot use ADFS as we maintain a separate database with all the user info as a part of asp.net membership role provider.
Can someone guide me on how this can be achieved.

Appreciate your time.

Comment: Should Not be asked to re-authenticate ! - correction

Comment: I too find myself stuck on this question. Microsoft clearly describes this process using ADFS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446525.aspx) but I really wonder if there's a much easier way. With Sharepoint 2007, we just passed cookies. Anyone ever done this with Sharepoint 2010 and on?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the SP2007 model was a lot easier but not extensible.

Are these web applications on the same SharePoint farm? 
The SharePoint STS can be shared across multiple web apps as long they live within the same farm. You can configure your webapps and the Sharepoint STS to use FBA with your custom membership/role provider.

We managed to implement a similar scenario but the webapp1 was living on Sharepoint 2010/2013 and the webapp2 was an standard ASP.NET app. The user logs in on webapp1 and the ticket was shared across to webapp2. The same scenario can be used to share tokens between Sharepoint web apps as long they live within the farm. (Your Sharepoint STS will internally talk to your membership/role provider however behind the scenes a FedAuth token will be created as your SP web apps only understand claims)

Hope this makes sense, if not let me know.

Gerardo Diaz